# Constraints wrong according to mySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, innodb

Not sure what I'm overseeing here, according to mySQL my constrains are malformed (the remarked part).
Didn't figure out yet what I did wrong using the allmighty internet search engine with G.
Advice greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `documentsCustomers` (
    `id` INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `document` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `customer` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `document` (`document`),
    INDEX `customer` (`customer`) 
/*,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_document` FOREIGN KEY (`document`) REFERENCES `documents` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`customer`) REFERENCES `customers` (`ID`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
*/
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Note it is actually correct, one table having ID capital and the other one not.

Comment: What is the error message (complete, copy/paste, don't paraphrase)

Comment: /* SQL Error (1005): Can't create table 'development.documentsCustomers' (errno: 150)

Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed */

Comment: Show the field definitions for documents.id and customers.ID.

Comment: `customers`.`ID` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`documents`.`id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
both are primary_key. by seeing this, i believe it's the 'unsigned' flag. let me check that quick.

Comment: Yep, it was the unsigned flag I've overseen on `customers`. From the error message, I believed the creation code was malformed and not that the row types mismatch. Thanks a bunch!